# почему не работает .html()?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
========================================================
...
<body>

    <div class="window"></div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="bg-color">
            <button class="btn-color">Black</button>
            <button class="btn-color">Gray</button>
            <button class="btn-color">White</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
========================================================
$(function () {
  var btnColor = $('.btn-color'); 
    btnColor[1].html('test');
});
========================================================
```

Comment: У вас `btnColor[1]` не Jquery элемент, а обычный нативный. Сделайте так, чтобы обратиться именно к JQuery элементу: `btnColor.eq(1).html('test');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что jQuery.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-color')[1].innerHTML = 'test';
```

```html
<div class="window"></div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="bg-color">
            <button class="btn-color">Black</button>
            <button class="btn-color">Gray</button>
            <button class="btn-color">White</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```